# Shrink tuples in list of tuples in Python

Tags: list, tuples, element

I have a list of tuples. How can I drop some elements in all tuples? E.g.

```
[...,(23188,'Bob',1944,'Dentist','Houston'),(44512,'Charlie',1961,'Teacher','Boston'), ...]
```

should become

```
[...,('Bob',1944,'Houston'),('Charlie',1961,'Boston'), ...]
```

Comment: [`[(b, c, e) for (a, b, c, d, e) in L]`](https://repl.it/GhmN/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this.

```
>>>
>>> l1 = [(23188,'Bob',1944,'Dentist','Houston'),(44512,'Charlie',1961,'Teacher'
,'Boston')]
>>>
>>> import operator
>>> pickup = operator.itemgetter(1,2,4)
>>> map(pickup,l1)
[('Bob', 1944, 'Houston'), ('Charlie', 1961, 'Boston')]
>>>
```